# Command execution timeout for command: (AUTH), params: (password masked) - Redisson client

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster, redisson

I am trying to connect to redis server using redisson client in spring boot application. While connecting to redis using user name and password, getting the below exception

> Command execution timeout for command: (AUTH), params: (password masked), Redis client: [addr=redis://:]

**But I am able to connect to same redis instance with same credentials using redis insight but facing issue while accessing from spring boot application using redisson client.**

I am using bitnami master slave redis set up. Loading the redis configurations as below

```
Config config = new Config();

config.useSingleServer().setAddress("redis://" + serverURI).setUsername("username").setPassword("password");

return Redisson.create(config);
```

Providing the password as a normal string.

Do we need to mask or unmask the password?

Comment: I tested with Lettuce redis client with the same host name and credentials. It is working fine. Looks like, this issue is with redisson client only. I am using redisson dependency as below
`
              <dependency>
   <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
   <artifactId>redisson-spring-data-26</artifactId>
   <version>3.17.1</version>
  </dependency>  `

Comment: Today, I have added connection pool and time out configuration. Now the spring boot application is connecting to redis 5 out of 10 times. 

Getting intermittent time out issue. 

Do I need to add any other configurations??

Comment: Issue has been fixed by redisson team. Please find the resolution

https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/4311

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been fixed by redisson team. Please find the resolution github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/4311

Comment: I am using below code for a cluster node, >> String address = "redis://" + redisHost + ":" + redisPort; config.useClusterServers().addNodeAddress(address).setPassword(redisPassword); lettuce configuration works properly but not this. I amusing 3.17.6 version

Answer (score 2):

Please check if adding **port** explicitly in address resolves the issue.

```
 .setAddress("redis://host:port")
```

Also, if server has been setup with ssl then add params accourdingly. Following are must in that case.

```
.setAddress("rediss://host:port")
.setSslEnableEndpointIdentification(false);
```

Notice address has extra `s`, rediss - denotes connect over ssl